# Landsat harmonization problem while exporting NDVI time series to Google Docs with GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, landsat

I write a code that calculates the Landsat 7 and Landsat 8 Collection 2 Level 2 NDVI time series for given points and saves the results to Google Docs using GEE.
It was working well (I can get the NDVI time series file) until I added the Landsat-ETM to Landsat-OLI harmonization part to my code. Now it gives an error 'Image.date: Image '1_LE07_176033_20141118' does not have a 'system:time_start' property. (Error code: 3)'
I get the harmonization part from "Landsat ETM+ to OLI Harmonization" [tutorial](https://code.earthengine.google.com/798ae7a268f8e2c8022433b9562785c0).
I do not understand why a simple band math caused such an error. How can I revise my code for calculating NDVI values using the harmonized Landsat-ETM values?

Here is the [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fmaggie06%2FThesis-Denemeler%3ANDVI_Collection2) to my code.

```
// Import the necessary libraries
var geometry = ee.FeatureCollection('users/maggie06/5stations3pixels');


//Image Collection Filter
var colFilter = ee.Filter.and(
    ee.Filter.bounds(geometry), ee.Filter.date('2014-09-22', '2017-07-02'),
    ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 50), ee.Filter.lt('GEOMETRIC_RMSE_MODEL', 10),
    ee.Filter.or(
        ee.Filter.eq('IMAGE_QUALITY', 9),
        ee.Filter.eq('IMAGE_QUALITY_OLI', 9)));

// Filter the images to only include images with less than 50% cloud coverage
var filtered_l7 = l7.filter(colFilter);
var filtered_l8 = l8.filter(colFilter);

// Applies scaling factors.
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
//  var thermalBand = image.select('ST_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true);
//              .addBands(thermalBand, null, true);
}

var scaled_l7 = filtered_l7.map(applyScaleFactors);
var scaled_l8 = filtered_l8.map(applyScaleFactors);

// Rename the Landsat 7 bands in the collection
var renamed_l7 = scaled_l7.map(function(image) {
  return image.select(['SR_B1', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B7', 'QA_PIXEL'],
                       ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'NIR', 'swir1', 'swir2', 'pixel_qa']);
});

// Rename the Landsat 8 bands in the collection
var renamed_l8 = scaled_l8.map(function(image) {
  return image.select(['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7', 'QA_PIXEL'],
                       ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'NIR', 'swir1', 'swir2', 'pixel_qa']);
});

// Mask clouds, cloud shadows, and snow
// Define the mask function using the pixel_qa band
var mask = function(img) {
  var qa = img.select(['pixel_qa']);
  // Clouds
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3).neq(0);
  // Cloud shadows
  var shadow = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 4).neq(0);
  // Snow
  var snow = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5).neq(0);
  
  var mask = cloud.or(shadow).or(snow);
  return img.updateMask(mask.not());
};

var masked_l7 = renamed_l7.map(mask);
var masked_l8 = renamed_l8.map(mask);

//Harmonization Formula
var coefficients = {
  itcps: ee.Image.constant([0.0003, 0.0088, 0.0061, 0.0412, 0.0254, 0.0172]).multiply(10000),
  slopes: ee.Image.constant([0.8474, 0.8483, 0.9047, 0.8462, 0.8937, 0.9071])
};

// Define Transform Function
function etmToOli(img) {
  return img.select(['blue', 'green', 'red', 'NIR', 'swir1', 'swir2'])
      .multiply(coefficients.slopes)
      .add(coefficients.itcps)
      .round()
      .toShort()
      .addBands(img.select('pixel_qa'));
}

// Apply the Transform function to the L7 ETM collection
var harmonised_l7 = masked_l7.map(etmToOli);

// Merge the two collections
var merged_collections = harmonised_l7.merge(masked_l8);

// Define the NDVI function
var NDVI = function(img) {
  var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['NIR','red']).rename('NDVI');
  return img.addBands(ndvi);
};

// Apply the NDVI function to the collection
var ndvi_collection = merged_collections.map(NDVI);

// Function to map over the FeatureCollection - Saving NDMI values to GoogleDrive:
var extractNDVI = function(feat) {
  // get feature geometry
  var geom = feat.geometry();
  // function to iterate over the yearly ImageCollection
  // the initial object for the iteration is the feature
  var addProp = function(img, f) {
    // cast Feature
    var newf = ee.Feature(f);
    // get date as string
    var date = img.date().format();
    // extract the value (first) of 'waterClass' in the feature
    var value = img.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), geom, 30).get('NDVI');
    // if the value is not null, set the values as a property of the feature. The name of the property will be the date
    return ee.Feature(ee.Algorithms.If(value,
                                       newf.set(date, ee.String(value)),
                                       newf.set(date, ee.String('No data'))));
  };
  var ndvi_values = ee.Feature(ndvi_collection.iterate(addProp, feat));
  return ndvi_values;
};

var ndvi_values = geometry.map(extractNDVI);

// Export the NDVI values and dates to an Excel file
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ndvi_values,
  description: 'Kirsehir_5s_NDVI_harmonised',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Comment: Could you add the code to the question as well? Links tend to expire after some time.

Comment: @Nikos I added my code.